# update row and INCREMENT one to that

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

update carstock set nofstock INCREMENT BY 1 where  and cid=" + TextBox1.Text;

Comment: Please describe the question well!

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Euh, you probably want this:

> "update carstock set nofstock = nofstock + 1 where cid=@cid"

And as your example isn't safe for SQL Injection, you'd better use SQL Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
 update carstock set nofstock INCREMENT BY 1 where some_field="some_condition" and cid=" + TextBox1.Text";
```

you have either missed out one condition or have put `where` by mistake.